# jQuery scrollTo - how to stop embeded swf file when scrolling?

Tags: jquery, flash, scrollto

Actually the question is in the title.
I use the "flashembed" feature of the jQuery tools within a site that is using scrollTo as well. The embeded swf file is my banner and right now it is running continiously. When I scroll to another hash it keeps running in the back and makes the scrolling a little bumby.

Does anybody know how to stop the swf file from playing while the scrollTo script is running?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be you can try to stop the flash clip onscroll event if it is in playing state.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option, the simplest way to do this would be to create exposed methods of the play() and stop() actions of the swf. Once you do that, you can call them before the scrolling animation begins, and when it ends.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me but if I do not see an exact example of the codeline I would have to type in, I can not imagine what to do. Thanks anyway.